# multiple "has many through" with eloquent of laravel

Tags: php, sql, laravel, orm, eloquent

I came accros a problem with laravel's ORM, eloquent and found no solution yet.

I have some tables as follows

**Team**

```
 - id
 - name
```

**User**

```
 - id
 - name
 - role
 - team_id
```

**Student_Info**

```
 - id
 - user_id
 - data1
 - data2
 - etc ...
```

**Project**

```
 - id
 - student_id
 - name
```

Now, I want to query all projects a certain `team`, where `team = 'some team'`

Now the thing here is, without an ORM, it's simple, I would have done multiple joins in raw SQL.

However, because all these tables have a common column "name" I will have to alias all this stuff, which is really boring

With eloquent I can't find a way to do this query using "has many through" because it only allows on intermediate and I can't do a raw SQL as the alis thing is really a pain in the ass and as it would be very difficult to map the result to laravel's Models

Comment: use team_id also in project table.

Comment: well, that's a very bad practice in database design, because in the facts, the project doesn't directly belong to a project but to a student so it would created duplication and create confusion in what the model really is.

Answer (score 10):

There is no native relationship for this case.

I created a `HasManyThrough` relationship with unlimited levels: [Repository on GitHub](https://github.com/staudenmeir/eloquent-has-many-deep)

After the installation, you can use it like this:

```php
class Team extends Model {
    use \Staudenmeir\EloquentHasManyDeep\HasRelationships;

    public function projects() {
        return $this->hasManyDeep(Project::class, [User::class, StudentInfo::class],
            [null, null, 'student_id']);
    }
}

$projects = Team::where('name', 'some team')->first()->projects;
```

Answer (score 2):

Try with relationship existence. This assumes you have all relationships properly defined

```
$projects = Project::whereHas('students.user.team', function ($query) {
    $query->where('name', '=', 'some team');
})->get();
```

That's 3 levels of nesting. Never tested. However, if you already define a Project-User relationship via `hasManyThrough()` you can shorten it to 2 levels only.

```
$projects = Project::whereHas('user.team', function ($query) {
    $query->where('name', '=', 'some team');
})->get();
```

Those will give you the data for projects only. If you also want the the intermediate data, use eager loading instead with `with()`. Just replace `whereHas()` by `with()`.

```
$projects = Project::with('user.team', function ($query) {
    $query->where('name', '=', 'some team');
})->get();
```

Comment: i tried this before but it did work on simple queries but on complexe ones with filters and stuff it didn't (and the queries made up by laravel were pretty... shit lol but after all it's an ORM so can't have performance + simplicity of use)

Comment: Interesting. Can I do it inverse? Using the original question is it possible get teams with projects by a project_id and projects eager loaded?